# MTAdmob is not showing up in release version

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

MTAdmob is not showing up in release. I am not sure why, I followed the tutorial below.

Nuget = https://github.com/marcojak/MTAdmob

AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID" 
           android:value="ca-app-pub-222222~33321" />
...
```

MainActivity.cs

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        ...
        MobileAds.Initialize(ApplicationContext);
...
    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
....
```

home.xaml

```
<admob:MTAdView  HeightRequest="50"
                        AdsId="ca-app-pub-23322332/23323" />
```

Comment: Could do you show the ads on debug mode? What ad unit ID you used for? The new one or the one provided by google AdMob? If you create a new one, the New test devices typically start serving test ads in your app  for some time. May be few hours or few days.

Comment: ads doesnt show up in debug mode. Yes I am using unitID from google admob website. I did wainted 1 week. maybe have to wait a month

Comment: Have you check all the parameters like TestDevices? If you are sure you provided all the details correctly, it needs more time.